# WPF databinding of ICommand "freezes" after multiple Button clicks

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

This is my first time trying to databind an ICommand.  I have a digital LED control that I would like to act like a Button, so I changed the DataTemplate for a Button control to look like an LED:

LED.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="LedControlDatabindingTest.LED"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             x:Name="root"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=root}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="{Binding LEDOrientation, FallbackValue=Vertical}">
        <!-- LED portion -->
            <Button BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" Click="Button_Click">
                <Button.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" Margin="3" Height="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=LEDSize, FallbackValue=16}"
                                     Width="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=LEDSize, FallbackValue=16}"
                                     Fill="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=LEDColor, FallbackValue=Green}"
                                     StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" Margin="3" Height="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=LEDSize, FallbackValue=16}"
                                     Width="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=LEDSize, FallbackValue=16}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <Ellipse.Fill>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.5,1.0">
                                        <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                                                <TranslateTransform X="0.02" Y="0.3"/>
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#00000000"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0.4" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                                </Ellipse.Fill>
                            </Ellipse>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Button.ContentTemplate>
            </Button>
            <!-- label -->
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding LEDLabel, FallbackValue=0}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I want the host application to be able to databind to properties like size, color, and label of the LED.  In addition, I want to be able to bind to a command handler.

LED.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace LedControlDatabindingTest {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for LED.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class LED : UserControl
    {
        public static DependencyProperty LEDColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "LEDColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(LED));
        public Brush LEDColor
        {
            get { return this.GetValue(LEDColorProperty) as Brush; }
            set { 
                this.SetValue( LEDColorProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static DependencyProperty LEDSizeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "LEDSize", typeof(int), typeof(LED));
        public int LEDSize
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(LEDSizeProperty); }
            set { 
                SetValue( LEDSizeProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static DependencyProperty LEDLabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "LEDLabel", typeof(string), typeof(LED));
        public string LEDLabel
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(LEDLabelProperty); }
            set { 
                SetValue( LEDLabelProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static DependencyProperty LEDOrientationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "LEDOrientation", typeof(Orientation), typeof(LED));
        public Orientation LEDOrientation
        {
            get { return (Orientation)GetValue(LEDOrientationProperty); }
            set { 
                SetValue( LEDOrientationProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty LEDClickedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LEDClicked", typeof(ICommand), typeof(LED), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public ICommand LEDClicked
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(LEDClickedProperty); }
            set { SetValue( LEDClickedProperty, value); }
        }

        public LED()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LEDClicked.Execute( null);
        }
    }
}
```

My test application is simple.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="LedControlDatabindingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LedControlDatabindingTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="70" Width="250">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Digital Inputs:" />
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableDigitalInputs}">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:LED LEDLabel="{Binding Index}" LEDColor="{Binding Color}" LEDSize="12" LEDClicked="{Binding Clicked}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

There are so no-nos in my code-behind, like the DataContext for my application, but I think for the purposes of this demo it's okay for now.

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace LedControlDatabindingTest {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private class DigitalInputData : ViewModelBase
        {
            private Brush _color;
            public Brush Color 
            {
                get { return _color; }
                set {
                    _color = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }

            public int Index { get; set; }
            public ICommand Clicked { get; set; }
            private bool _state;

            public DigitalInputData( int index, Brush on_color)
            {
                Index = index;
                Color = Brushes.LightGray;

                Clicked = new RelayCommand( () => {
                    // get current state of this digital input and then toggle it
                    _state = !_state;
                    // read back and update here until I get threaded updates implemented                    
                    Color = _state ? on_color : Brushes.LightGray;
                });
            }
        }

        private List<DigitalInputData> _inputs = new List<DigitalInputData>();
        public ICollectionView AvailableDigitalInputs { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // For this example only, set DataContext in this way
            DataContext = this;

            for( int i=0; i<4; i++) {
                _inputs.Add( new DigitalInputData( i, Brushes.Green));
            }
            AvailableDigitalInputs = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView( _inputs);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this application, everything renders properly and according to my databound properties.  The click handler works as well, and toggles the state of the LED.

**But when I click the LED button numerous times, at some point (maybe after 20 clicks or so), it stops calling my databound ICommand.  Why?**

Comment: Your `LED` control can be taken out of `UserControl` and used in a `DataTemplate`, as the UC is pretty expensive to use. Those Bindings that you want to use will be available for you in your `DataTemplate` anyway. Also try to get some info about your Bindings `xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"` then`LEDClicked="{Binding Clicked, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"`.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I found out by accident you don't actually need the namespace for PresentationTraceSources -- just `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` works fine for me. Saves a lot of trouble finding a copy of the namespace attribute every time.

Comment: @XAMIMAX I will try that to see if the problem goes away, thanks.  I wonder why the question I have presented here is so bad that it got a -1.

Comment: Nice one @EdPlunkett! That is a good find! And another thing Dave, I think that passing VM as a parameter to a main View Model here would work much better and it would save to have so many instances of `Clicked` Command.

Comment: @XAMIMAX thanks, I am working on the DataTemplate part first.  But I would still like to know exactly why the LED control toggles the color as I would like, but only does it a set number of times before it completely stops working...

Comment: @XAMIMAX I switched to using a DataTemplate and removed the UC.  My databindings inside of the template don't work, but the Button Command binding works fine.  And the command handler still stops executing after several mouse clicks.

Answer (score 0):

I got lucky and figured out a solution to the "freezing" problem, although I do not understand the technical reasoning.

In my DigitalInputData constructor, I created the handler for the RelayCommand using a lambda function instead of passing a reference to a handler.  Once I switched over to passing the handler to the RelayCommand constructor, it worked great.